# How to always paste to clipboard?

Tags: os-clipboard

I am searching for an option to always paste to the system clipboard when using any kind of yank action, because I want to use Vim as the scrollback buffer for Kitty.

I have already tried

`clipboard=unnamed`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean copy into the system clipboard?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yes

Comment: `:set clipboard=unnamed` or `unnamedplus` should work. Does your vim include `+clipboard` in the output of `:version`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt unnamedplus works. This should be added to the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @neolith it is already in the documentation. Please feel free to come up with a doc PR if something is unclear.

Comment: I can only see https://pastebin.com/hMzRPd60. There is nothing about unnamedplus

Comment: `:help 'clipboard'` has the full details.

Comment: @MartinTournoij It was already answered and I created a PR to add it to the docs

Answer (score 0):

So the question was answered by @christian-brabandt. I had to use `unnamedplus`.